# PopupWindow update() animation

Tags: android

Is there a way to animate `PopupWindow` when issuing `update()` method? I'm changing my popup's position there, so it would be nice if I could smoothly slide the popup to its destination instead of just "jumping". I know I can easily animate the PopupWindow's entering and exiting via adding these items to its style:

```
<style name="MyPopup">
    <item name="@android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_in_right</item>
    <item name="@android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/slide_out_to_right</item>
</style>
```

But I'm interested in its position updating animation.

Comment: yes,  there is update (int x, int y, int width, int height) method you can use,  or you already did it but have some probs with it?

Comment: @pskink update() method just moves the Popup to the new location. I want to animate this movement

Comment: use ObjectAnimator then, or ValueAnimator